# how to check if line is cutting stock price

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am trying to draw trendlines . i have peaks and connecting all of them with  lines . like from first peak to second and from first peak to third i.e from first peak to all the other peaks and second peaks to all the other peaks and so on

```
peaks = [(3.0, 134.39999389648438), (12.0, 134.25), (17.0, 135.0)]
from (3.0, 134.39999389648438) to (12.0, 134.25)
from (3.0, 134.39999389648438) to (17.0, 135.0)
from (12.0, 134.25) to (17.0, 135.0)
```

[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qFE9.png) 
in 1st image lines A and B are valid but not C so i want to remove C

[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J04DK.png) in 2nd image - lines A , B ,F are valid but not the others so i want to remove them as it is cutting the price . so how to do it ? . i have starting(x1,y1) and ending(x2,y2) coordinates of lines

Comment: How are you drawing those lines? What is preventing you from deleting the lines of code that draw the lines you do not want?

Comment: like this  - x = [high_points[i][0],next_point[0]]  , y = [high_points[i][1],next_point[1]] ,       plt.plot(x,y,linewidth=1) . i can delete the lines but first  i need to get the lines which are crossing the stock price .